# Extracting paragraph breaks from OCR text?

Tags: python, latex, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to recreate the paragraphs and indentations from the output of OCR'd image text, like so:

**Input** (imagine that this is an image, not typed):

[image]

**Output** (with a few mistakes):

[image]

As you can see, no paragraph breaks or indentations are preserved.

Using Python, I tried an approach like this, but it doesn't work (fails too often):

**Code**:

```
def smart_format(text):
  textList = text.split('\n')
  temp = ''

  averageLL = sum([len(line) for line in textList]) / len(textList)

  for line in textList:
    if (line.strip().endswith('!') or line.strip().endswith('.') or line.strip().endswith('?')) and not line.strip().endswith('-'):
      if averageLL - len(line) > 7:
        temp += '{{ paragraph }}' + line + '\n'
      else:
        temp += line + '\n'
    else:
      temp += line + '\n'

  return temp.replace(' -\n', '').replace('-\n', '').replace(' \n', '').replace('\n', ' ').replace('{{ paragraph }}', '\n\n      ')
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as how I could recreate this layout? I'm working with old books, so I was hoping to re-typeset them with LaTeX, as it's quite simple to create a Python script to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, are you looking only at the text output and guessing where paragraph breaks should have been? Or is there something else to it?

Comment: I have the source image files, but it would be nice to just work with the outputted text files. I'm trying to implement @Nick ODell's answer below, but my OpenCV skills are pretty rusty...

Comment: This wouldn't by chance be inserting paragraph breaks *before* the last line of a paragraph instead of *after*, would it?

Comment: What software is doing the OCR? Some can be configured to provide line breaks.

Comment: @Mu Mind It seems to be (facepalm). Let's try running this again...

Comment: @le dorfier I'm using `tesseract` compiled from SVN a few weeks ago. It's the only one which is free and produces good results (almost perfect for English texts). There seems to be some document analysis going on, but I have no idea whether it can do what I want it to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can break up the image into multiple paragraphs by looking at the [entropy](https://web.archive.org/web/20110314200155/http://brainacle.com/calculating-image-entropy-with-python-how-and-why.html) of each 5-10 pixel horizontal slice. Although this is usually used to create "interesting" thumbnails from larger images or videos, you can also use it to identify the presence or absence of text. Here's how.

You divide the image into a bunch of horizontal strips, each 5-10 pixels tall. If a strip is not "busy" then you can assume that there is no text there. You can use this to isolate paragraphs. Now, you take each paragraph individually, and feed it into your OCR.

Comment: Huh, that's pretty cool. I'll try doing that. I was hoping for a way to do this without splitting the image, but if it works, it works.

Comment: Well, I ended up doing this in the end. As line height is almost constant, I scan the entropy of every single row (6000px takes around 10 seconds), extract the line height, and from there, scan strips of pixels. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to know you got your problem sorted.

Comment: Link is broken.. entropy sounds like what I'm looking for with tesseract though so thanks.

Comment: @Pogrindis Thanks for the heads up, fixed link.

Comment: Nice one, in my case I was having some difficulty actually getting the text area using tesseract, so went with just cv2, using the sampling and playing with the threshold. Maybe with some learning, it will identify better but your idea to break it up optimized the processing, so I would give you double points if i could.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to tell if the first word on a line could have easily fit on the previous line, indicating an intentional newline, instead of purely looking for short lines. Apart from that (and paying close attention to punctuation like you're doing in your example), I'd think the only other option is going back to the original images.